# How to Dim and Set Variables to create a Do While loop by using the find function and offset to cut-paste to another place

Tags: vba, excel

Can you suggest what is wrong with code? A Run-time Error '424 "Object required" highlights the beginning of code (Set CloseddateCell). Using a do loop because there are different types of coupons and the report generates different transactions each time. Not sure if it is the loop or naming of Dim is correct…
I want to loop through column (3) find “Closed Date/Time” cut/paste “CouponType” in column(2) Alongside each transaction that is under its CouponType.

```
Sub cdformatdata()

Dim closeddatecell As Range
Dim coupontype As String
Dim firstaddress As Range
Dim newcouponplace As Range



Set closeddatecell = Cells.Find(What:="Closed Date/Time", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
                        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
                        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

Do
    If ActiveCell.Value = (closeddatecell) Then
        coupontype = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Cells.Cut
        newcouponplace = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial
    End If

    Set closeddatecell = closeddatecell.FindNext(closeddatecell)

Loop While Not closeddatecell Is Nothing And closeddatecell.Address <> firstaddress And Selection.Value <> ""


End Sub
```

Comment: remove the .select at the end of the find statement.

Answer (score 1):

A few errors in your code in addition to @Scott Craner's comment - try this:

```
Sub cdformatdata()

Dim closeddatecell As Range
Dim firstaddress As String

    With ActiveSheet.Columns(3)

        Set closeddatecell = .Find(What:="Closed Date/Time", After:=.Cells(1), _
                                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)

        If Not closeddatecell Is Nothing Then
            firstaddress = closeddatecell.Address
            Do
                closeddatecell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy closeddatecell.Offset(0, -1)
                closeddatecell.Offset(-1, 0).Clear

                Set closeddatecell = .FindNext(closeddatecell)

            Loop While (Not closeddatecell Is Nothing) And _
                 closeddatecell.Address <> firstaddress

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```